# Change JDK in IntelliJ seems not working

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm on Windows, I've already set the Path to JDK 1.8  in Environment Variables.
Also in Project Structure, I've already changed to it.  I have a Maven project.

On command line, if I use `mvn --version'  I see

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 15:44:56+0700)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.8.0_77, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

However, in IntelliJ, if I hit the Run button, it always points to JDK 1.7, and an error is thrown (since my maven project requires java 8). How do I change that? Thanks

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin\java" -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\m2.conf -Dmaven.home=C:\apache-maven-3.0.4 -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.5\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher --no-plugin-registry --fail-fast --strict-checksums --update-snapshots -f C:\Users\Tung\server-pinbike\api-pinbike2\pom.xml install
```

**Update**
After following @BevyQ tip, I found that the JRE of Maven runner was pointing to Jre7, that's the reason.

See screenshot below, hope it helps someone.

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/project-page.html

Comment: one solution to this could be removing the older java version from your machine

Comment: Have you looked at your run configuration? click the runner tab and see what it says

Comment: On Linux, IntelliJ seemingly randomly changes my projects between JDKs 7 and 8.  But I haven't bothered paying enough attention to write a good bug report.

Comment: @BevynQ thanks, that's a great tip

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked your modules settings?

> In ***Project Structure***, click ***Modules->"Your modules"->Dependencies*** to see what SDK you are using.

And you should check the ***Run configurations*** too.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to repo your scenario by setting the Project SDK to 1.7 then set them module SDK to 1.8.

The version you got by using commend line, is the version that windows is using. It doesn't mean that version is applying to you project or your module in IntelliJ.

**So, please double check if you set both project and module's SDK to 1.8.**

Below are some screen shots of my repo.

[I set module SDK to 1.8. And set Project SDK to 1.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNH5j.png)

[Mvn version is 1.8. But it will using 1.7 when I run the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aotX.png)